# Adding custom cart price with Ajax in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to add a custom price to the cart using the following function (in functions.php):

```
//Change cart item price
function add_custom_price_callback( $cart_object ) {

$custom_price = intval($_POST['p_m']);
$target_product_id = intval($_POST['s_o_v']);         

foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $value ) {

    //Single product
    if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }
    //For variation
    if ( $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
        $value['data']->price = $custom_price;
    }

}    
die();    
}
```

add_action( 'wp_ajax_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price_callback' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price_callback' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price_callback' );
If I use static values on the variables the function works but I need to set the variables dynamically with an Ajax call.

I have added Ajax in "functions.php" by using:

```
//jQuery / Ajax on site
function site_scripts() {
    //jQ
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ww_site_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/ww_site_script.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
    //Ajax
     wp_localize_script( 'ww_site_script', 'ajax_p',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_scripts' );
```

And here is my Ajax call:

```
//Send ajax values    
$( '.single_add_to_cart_button' ).click(function() {
    console.log(s_o_v); 
    console.log(p_m);

    var data = {
        action: 'add_custom_price',
        p_m: p_m,
        s_o_v : s_o_v
    };

    $.post( ajax_p.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        console.log( response );
    }, 'json');
    });
```

The "console.log(respons);" gets the values that are echoed in the function but the admin-ajax returns 0. How do I send the values to the "add_custom_price_callback" function?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your add_custom_price_callback() as follows. Untested but should work.

```
function add_custom_price_callback() {
    $custom_price = intval($_POST['p_m']);
    $target_product_id = intval($_POST['s_o_v']);         

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $key=>$value ) {

        //Single product
        if ( $value['product_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
             $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
        }
        //For variation
        if ( $value['variation_id'] == $target_product_id ) {
             $value['data']->set_price($custom_price);
        }
   }
   //to check if is work or not       
   wp_send_json(array($value['data']->get_price($custom_price)));   
}
```